# How to remove decimal point from a double value after converting it to a string

Tags: java, android

I want to remove a decimal point from a `double` value. I tried converting it to string

```
double intify(double a)
{
    String s=Double.toString(a);
    String s2=s.replaceAll(".","");
     a=Double.parseDouble(s2);
    
    return a;
    
}
```

If I pass 123.4567 it should return 1234567.

Comment: How should the code handle fixed decimal numbers? What result do you expect for the input `13.5` or the input `3.33333333...`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) replaces a regex. You should use [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) instead:

```
String s2 = s.replace(".", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replaceAll use [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method of String:

```
String s2 = s.replace(".", "");
```

As "." has a special meaning in regex and replaceAll treats source string i.e. first parameter as regex.

Comment: Both this answer and @Mureinik's fail in the following two cases: 1) if the passed in double is an integer, and 2) if the passed in double is in scientific notation. In both cases the returned value is the original number * 10, which is probably not what the original poster expected.

Answer (score 0):

The below solves the issue of an integer being passed in (`123` or `123.0`), or a double in scientific notation (`1.23E7`):

`Double.parseDouble(Double.toString(a).replaceAll("[.](?0$)?",""));`

In your code, just change the `replaceAll` string to `[.](?0$)?`, which states "Remove the decimal as well as the number 0 if it is right after the decimal and there's nothing after it".

Answer (score 0):

```
    Double i=Double.parseDouble("String with double value");


    Log.i(tag,"display double "+i);


    try{
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);// set as you need
        String myStringmax = nf.format(i);


        String result = myStringmax.replaceAll("[-+.^:,]","");
        Double i=Double.parseDouble(result);

       int max= Integer.parseInt(result);


    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("ex="+e);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Your question isn't well-enough defined for a general answer, but if you want to get rid of the fractional part, just parse it as a double and then cast it to `int` or `long`.